# dplyr mutate: Excluding observations similar to the current one

Tags: r, mean, dplyr

I have some data like this:

```
X   Y
-----
A   1
A   2
B   3
B   4
C   5
C   6
```

I would like to add a new column with values equal to the mean of all Ys in rows where X is not euqal to X of the current observation.
In this particlar case we would get

```
X   Y   Mean
-------------------
A   1   (3+4+5+6)/4
A   2   (3+4+5+6)/4
B   3   (1+2+5+6)/4
B   4   (1+2+5+6)/4
C   5   (1+2+3+4)/4
C   6   (1+2+3+4)/4
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can likely do this more succinctly, but this will get you the result.

You essentially create a column which contains the total observations and sum of records for the whole data.frame. Then you group by the `X` column and repeat the process, by taking the difference you can calculate your mean.

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(X = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                 Y = c(1:6))
```

---

#### solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(total_sum = sum(Y),
         total_obs = n()) %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  mutate(group_sum = sum(Y),
         group_obs = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(other_group_sum = total_sum - group_sum,
         other_group_obs = total_obs - group_obs,
         other_mean = other_group_sum/other_group_obs) %>%
  select(X, Y, other_mean)
```

---

#### result

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  X         Y other_mean
  <fct> <int>      <dbl>
1 A         1       4.50
2 A         2       4.50
3 B         3       3.50
4 B         4       3.50
5 C         5       2.50
6 C         6       2.50
```